# Making Multiple Instances of Spotify-web-api-js

Tags: javascript, oop, instance, spotify

I am making a React App with the [Spotify-web-api-js](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js) package, which is a wrapper over the Spotify API.

It can be instantiated and used like this:

```js
let SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-js');
let spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
spotifyApi.setAccessToken("AccessToken")
spotifyApi.getPlaylist("playlistLink")
```

The access token is required for each user.

In my app, I need 2 instances of the wrapper, one for each user/access-token. But when I make 2 instances, it seems like they are both the same instance.

```js
let SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-js');
let spotifyApi1 = new SpotifyWebApi();
let spotifyApi2 = new SpotifyWebApi();

console.log(spotifyApi1.getAccessToken());
console.log(spotifyApi2.getAccessToken());

spotifyApi1.setAccessToken("Hello");
spotifyApi2.setAccessToken("Bye");

console.log(spotifyApi1.getAccessToken());
console.log(spotifyApi2.getAccessToken());
```

prints:

```
null
null
Bye
Bye
```

Where I expected it to print:

```
null
null
Hello
Bye
```

The access token in both instances is set to the latest set statement.

Same thing even if I write:

```js
let SpotifyWebApi1 = require('spotify-web-api-js');
let SpotifyWebApi2 = require('spotify-web-api-js');
let spotifyApi1 = new SpotifyWebApi1();
let spotifyApi2 = new SpotifyWebApi2();
```

I don't know if this is a problem with the wrapper, or my lacking JavaScript skills.

**Additional context**

I installed the wrapper package using npm.
[Here is my project](https://github.com/parsasaeedi/interspot). I instantiate the wrappers in /src/Interspot.js and use them in /src/useSpotifyAPI.js

Comment: Looking at the source code of the library, they don't use `this.` to set properties, so I think it might be setting a global variable https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js/blob/master/src/spotify-web-api.js#L2052

Comment: I was able to reproduce this by adding a custom test in the library's `.spec.js` file